# Using textures to scatter geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, procedural

So, I just finished a procedure for mountain texture and I need to scatter trees only in places under the snow areas.

My idea was to use the same method as I did for mapping the snow in the shader editor with a texture coordinate --> separate xyz --> color ramp, but geometry nodes don't support texture coordinates.

Is there any way to add trees only in the green areas under the snow?

[image: I need trees in the green areas.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least two different options here:

- Either you distribute your instances with the help of an image texture.
- Or you distribute your instances according to the *Z-position* of your terrain.

Your question refers to the variant with the image texture:

[image]

1. Get your terrain with `Object Info`.
2. The node `Bounding Box` gives you the minimum and maximum position/extension of this mesh.
3. With `Map Range` you can now map the position of the faces of this range into another one. In this case the image texture needs a range from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,0)$ as input.
4. You can then feed the result as a vector into the `Image Texture` node that contains your image.
5. Depending on the colors of the image, you can now make comparisons which create a selection.
6. Based on this selection you create the points for your instances with the node `Distribute Points on Faces`.
7. At these points you can then instantiate your trees, swimming pools, or whatever with `Instance on Points`.

---

The other variant works directly with the *Z-position* of the terrain:

[image]

1. Here you simply separate the *Z-position* with `Separate XYZ` and directly compare this value with a value of your choice.
2. With this selection you continue as in the example above...

[image]

Comment: just as addition: if he would have set the material with GN, you can also separate/select by material like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/usCr9.png (Material selection node). Maybe result: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Aaw.jpg -> distributing just on green the "trees"

Comment: @Chris Thank you for this valuable tip!